# synchronous operation in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a stateful component in which i fetch a userlist in `componentDidMount()`. Right after I'm checking whether the list is empty, and if so, create a placeholder  to display.

Since the fetching of the list is an asynchronous operation I should probably not check for the empty list like so:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchUsersOfList());
  if (this.props.userBases.length === 0) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have this currently solved by writing the if statement inside a `componentDidUpdate()`:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.userBases.length === 0) {
    if (this.props.currentBase !== prevProps.currentBase) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I am using redux and updating the state after each function has run/completed.
The issue now is that each time I delay an operation like this I delay displaying data to the user. Eventually this adds up and is noticeable. Hence the times for users that they see turning loading-wheels increases.

Is there another, faster way to solve this concept?

Comment: if you are doing asynchronous  operations, then a redux middleware is your best option. Easy to implement.

Comment: Why don't you check if your data exists in your `render` method? Also, since this is an asynchronous operation a user always sees some spinners at some point. Maybe in the newer versions of React, `suspend` will handle that kind of situations. Am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: @devserkan what is _suspend_ ? I don't know this.. can you point me to a link?

Comment: Oops a typo there, not "suspend" it is "suspense" @ArupRakshit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g3g0Q_XVb4

Comment: @devserkan Either way, I was not aware of.. I will def watch it.. thanks mate.

Comment: Yes, Use redux middleware instead, saga or thunk.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm already using thunk. Please share in your own words how this will solve my thought  process above?

Comment: @Helle Sry, I'm mostly a saga guy. I suggested middleware because you're using async operation. A one example I'll comment it on this.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you're returning response payload from your action and throwing error as well.
You get your resolved promise in `then` like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.props.dispatch(fetchUsersOfList()).then((response)=>{
if (// your condition goes here") {
    ...
  }
 })
}
```

Feel free to ask any question

Comment: fetching a list like this in connection with Redux will not return a payload. The payload of the fetch will be handled by the reducer and implemented in the state

Comment: and you can return the API response from your action too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by a placeholder, but most probably you have one of two needs:

1. If your list is empty, show a message instead of a li. (No data found or something on that vein)
2. or Show some initial text while you wait for data (for e.x. Loading...)

The first is basically [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). in your `render` method, you can have something like:

```
if (this.props.userBases && this.props.userBases.length > 0 ) {
   return <Blah />
} else {
   return <Placeholder />
}
```

The 2nd challenge is essentially setting an [initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state). Idea is that you give your component an initial state and then when the async action has finished, it updates the state and react re-renders it. I am not using redux, but they seem to offer [a recipe](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/initializingstate) for it.

**Update** On closer reading of your question, I think you are using the lifecycles in the wrong way as well. I would highly recommend reading the official blog post on [async rendering in react](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) to understand the lifecycles better.

Comment: The problem now is that I have a conditional that says: execute when the length is 0. I then add a default user to the list, the state updates, but between re-rendering state show several times that there is no default user yet, hence the userbases.length continues to show 0. I end up with a bunch of the same default users until state shows !== 0

Answer (score 0):

Handle your subscription via connect method.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
const items = cartItemsSelector(state);
return {
    items,
    fetched: items !== null
}
};

export const CartItemListContainer = connect(
   mapStateToProps
)(CartItemListDisplay);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20669194)

Comment: Presentation and Container components, how the dispatch and subscribe can be handled via connect https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save things on state. You can return early from render with a different result. When the props change, render will be called again with newer props.

```
class MyComponent {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    if (!items || !items.length) return <span>Loading...</span>;

    return <List items={items} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to save this call to state because the placeholder item i am creating will be saved in the database